# How do I make my program understand a very similar phrase

Tags: python

For example if I wanted my program to run if the input was"no" but input was "NO" how do I make my program understand the input

Sorry if this does not make much sense I am very new to programming.

Comment: Convert input to lowercase before checking

Answer (score 0):

To make the input case-insensitive, convert it to lowercase before checking the value.

```
animal = input("Enter your favorite animal :) >").lower()

#the string you're checking for needs to be lowercase
if animal=="polarbear":
    print("Polar bears are cool!")
```

That means when I enter POlarBEAr it prints out Polar bears are cool!

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, computers don't understand whether something is wrong or right but if you are asking in terms of coding, its called checking if two strings are similar and its done this way :

1. trim the string -> basically remove whitespaces from front and back
2. make it lower case or upper case
3. check it with the expected string

This is how you code this:

```python
my_input_string = " RigHt "

answer = my_input_string.strip().lower()
if answer=="right":
   print("Hurray!! you have right answer")
else:
   print("Aww! your answer is wrong")
```

Comment: I think you meant `strip()` instead of `trim()`, strings in Python don't have a method named trim.

Comment: Could be... I am more of Java guy 